React & Typescript. Generic<Type> in children component
I'm creating a Form component and i have the following question.
How can i type the Input component to infer the Generic type from it's parent?
Here is an example.
type FormModel = Record<string, any>;
interface FormProps<T extends FormModel> {
  initialValues: T;
  children: ReactNode;
}

function Form<T extends FormModel>({ children }: FormProps<T>) {
  return <form>{children}</form>;
}

interface InputProps<T extends FormModel> {
  id: keyof T;
}

function Input<T extends FormModel>({ id }: InputProps<T>) {
  return <input name={id} id={id} />;
}

Form.Input = Input; // --> This input is not infering the Generic from Form.

interface Test {
  surname: string;
}
const Example = () => {
  const initialValues: Test = { surname: "Example" };
  return (
    <Form initialValues={initialValues}>
      <Form.Input id="" /> // --> This Id is not typed.
    </Form>
  );
};


is this possible?
Thank you
I've tried without success.
Creating The FormForm type with.
type FormType<T extends FormModel> = FC<FormProps<T>> & {
  Input: FC<InputProps<T>>;
};


Also i've tried infering the generic.
type GetGeneric<T> = T extends FC<FormProps<infer X>> ? X : never;

All this things did not work
